# How do I open localhost from MS Access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Application.FollowHyperlink _
          "https://www.localhost/Bowls/Bowlshome"
          "localhost/Bowls/Bowlshome"
```

Neither of the above work.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What does "Neither of the above work" mean?

Comment: I have also tried Application.FollowHyperlink _
          "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bowls\Bowlshome.php" (still no luck)

Comment: Why are you putting an underscore after FollowHyperlink? Is that intentional? Does it work if you do: `Application.FollowHyperlnk "https://www.google.com"` ?

Comment: This is my latest try. Application.FollowHyperlink "https://www.localhost/Bowls/Bowlshome.php" (error msg: cannot locate the internet server or proxy server

Comment: Does google work? Can you browse to localhost in your browser? Need more information.

Comment: My localhost program runs with NO problems in Google. (localhost/bowls/bowlshome.php). I want to run it within my access program called ENB.

Comment: .I have tried:                                       Application.FollowHyperlink "https://www.localhost/Bowls/Bowlshome.php"
Application.FollowHyperlink "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bowls\Bowlshome.php"
Application.FollowHyperlink "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\localhost\Bowls\Bowlshome.php"
Application.FollowHyperlink "localhost/Bowls/Bowlshome.php"
Application.FollowHyperlink https://www.localhost/Bowls/Bowlshome.php
Also not sure whether I have got the / \ correct. Error msg are can’t find the file.
Thanks Roy

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the protocol, and no www for localhost.

```
"http://localhost/Bowls/Bowlshome/"
```

or

```
"http://localhost/Bowls/Bowlshome.php"
```

Comment: Brilliant, "http://localhost/Bowls/Bowlshome.php" WORKS.

Comment: Brilliant "http://localhost/Bowls/Bowlshome.php" WORKS